# How can I Extract an Array from an Array of custom struct in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am making a **struct** called **personStruct**, which takes simple data like **age** and **name**. Here is this struct:

```
struct personStruct
{
    var name: String = String()
    var age: Int = Int()
}
```

then I am using this down class for extracting my wished arrays:

```
class PersonModel
{
    
    var persones: [personStruct] = [personStruct]()
    var countOfPersones: Int { persones.count }
    
    
    
    func personesAgeArray() -> [Int]
    {
        var returnArray: [Int] = [Int]()
        for item in persones { returnArray.append(item.age) }
        return returnArray
    }
    
    func personesNameArray() -> [String]
    {
        var returnArray: [String] = [String]()
        for item in persones { returnArray.append(item.name) }
        return returnArray
    }
   
}
```

And this is my use case of those struct and class:

```
let personModel: PersonModel = PersonModel()
personModel.persones = [personStruct(name: "bob", age: 30), personStruct(name: "Roz", age: 26), personStruct(name: "man", age: 40)]
print(personModel.personesAgeArray())
print(personModel.personesNameArray())
```

---

So as you see that class make that Job done!

**My Goal:** Do we have a real syntax or more efficiency way for making those Arrays? (I mean **personesAgeArray** and **personesNameArray**)

**My Super Goal:** I want **personesAgeArray** and **personesNameArray** get automatically builded/updated with adding new item to **persones**.

Comment: For a more "Swift" code: `func personesAgeArray() -> [Int] { return persones.map{ $0.age }}` maybe? But it's still working code to do a manual loop. For the rest, prefers using an uppercase for the first letter in struct and class names (`personStruct` -> `PersonStruct`), and naming might change.

Comment: I think you should forget about your super goal since it is overly complicated and will create a lot of overhead with little or no benefit.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I think so! but that would crazy if it would work? do you have any idea for me that I try? where I should start?

Comment: No, you would need to maintain 3 different properties and hence store data twice. A computed property is just as good

Comment: thanks! a lot! I think there is more costs than benefits! I forget it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

class Model {
    var people: [Person] = []
    var peopleCount: Int { people.count }
    var ages: [Int] { people.map(\.age) }
    var names: [String] { people.map(\.name) }
}
```

---

```
let model: Model = .init()
model.people = [.init(name: "bob", age: 30), .init(name: "Roz", age: 26), .init(name: "man", age: 40)]
print(model.ages)  // "[30, 26, 40]\n"
print(model.names) // "["bob", "Roz", "man"]\n"
model.people.append(.init(name: "Omid", age: 20))
print(model.ages)  // "[30, 26, 40, 20]\n"
print(model.names) // "["bob", "Roz", "man", "Omid"]\n"
```